# Efficient way to query work items updates via Visual Studio Team Service REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to query when bugs' state were changed to 'Active' for reporting purpose and have successfully retrieved required result by reading visual studio docs.

1. Get all work item ids I'm interested via [Work item query language](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql). There are a lot as I'm querying one-year data.
2. Use a for loop to call [updates API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/updates) for each id.
3. Parse updates API result to find *System.State* field.

The problem is that Step 2 is too **slow** because updates API only accepts one id each request.
Is there a way to get updates for work items in batch? It's also better if we can limit fields in updates API to ease Step 3.

Answer (score 1):

It’s mainly caused by step1 **returns the work items not only in current project but also in other projects**.

You may use below REST API for step1:

```
POST https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0
```

Content-Type: application/json

```
{
  "query": 
  "Select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State] 
  From WorkItems 
  Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' AND [State] = 'Active'"
}
```

Then it will return the Bugs which state is Active from all the team projects.

You just need to add a condition to **specify the current team project in where clause**:

- **If the team project WIT only has one Area** (no children Areas) and the name is same as team project name, you can use the REST API as:

  ```
  POST https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0
  ```

  Content-Type: application/json

  ```
  {
    "query": 
    "Select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State] 
    From WorkItems 
    Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' AND [State] = 'Active' AND [System.AreaPath] = 'projectname'"
  ```

  }
- **If the team project WIT has more than one Areas** (such as the Areas are: `projectname`, `projectname\child1`, `projectname\child2`), you can use below REST API:

  ```
  POST https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0
  ```

  Content-Type: application/json

  ```
  {
    "query": 
    "Select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State] 
    From WorkItems 
    Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' AND [State] = 'Active' AND [System.AreaPath] IN ('projectname', 'projectname\\child1', 'projectname\\child2)"
  }
  ```

Then the step2 will be faster and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but big bugs number is expected as I'm querying one year data. It's not related to project or area path as I've verified result manually against query editor in VSTS web site.

Comment: If you are using the first application/json example as I listed. It does contains work items in other project. And if you have confirmed all the returned work items from a certain project, the reason for step2 too slow may caused the large numbers of the work items.